# how to count in 2 dimension array

Tags: vb.net

I have a field, [Answer]

```
2;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3
2;3;4;3;1;1;1;2;2
3;1;3;2;1;1;1;1;1
2;1;4;2;1;1;1;1;1
```

The answer are from 1 (lowest) 4 (highest). I need to count columns. Ex, for question1, there are 3 number 2's; there is 1 number 3. Question 2 - there are 2 number 3's and 2 number 1's and so on. Assume all rows in datatable and the split function are fine. 
I have tried to use two dimension arrays, but the counts are not correct.

```
Dim ansArr(16, 3) As Integer   '2-D array; 17 questions and 4 possible answers
    For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1    'loop through a row of datatable
        Dim Answer() As String = dt.Rows(I).Item(3).Split(";") 'split answer and store into array
        For j As Integer = 0 To 16
            For k As Integer = 0 To 3
                k = (Val(Answer(j)))
                ansArr(j, k - 1) += 1
            Next
        Next
 Next
For Each a_ansArr As Integer In ansArr
        MessageBox.Show(a_ansArr.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: now whats wrong with your code?

Comment: it doesn't count right.

Comment: when I ran it, the ansArr(0,0) = 91, but I have only two rows of datatable. there is a bug somewhere inside the for loops but I can't figure it out

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand the data still.  The field example you show has 9 items per line.  Is that accurate, or should it be 17 items per line like your comment and array?

Comment: what will be the expected output?

Comment: It's 17 items = 17 questions. Those items listed above are just examples how they look like. The expect output is:
Q1: there are 2 count of 3's and 2 counts of 1's 
and so on

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Using your first row as sample:  "2;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3", when you say "count columns", are you wanting "there are eight 3's and one 2", are you trying to SUM all items in each row (26)?

Comment: No, SnookeC. I have to count columns, NOT rows. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your example above, is this what you're expecting?   
9 8 14 10 6 6 6 7 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding what you are wanting correctly I believe I see the issue.
The

```
For k As Integer = 0 To 3 
   k = (Val(Answer(j)))
   ansArr(j, k - 1) += 1
Next
```

appears to be counting then Answer at position j mutltiple times when you should only be counting each answer once. I believe that For loop is redunandt and should just be replaced with

```
k = (Val(Answer(j)))
ansArr(j,k-1) += 1
```

So the modified code would be

```
Dim ansArr(16, 3) As Integer   '2-D array; 17 questions and 4 possible answers
For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1    'loop through a row of datatable
    Dim Answer() As String = dt.Rows(I).Item(3).Split(";") 'split answer and store into array
    For j As Integer = 0 To 16
       k = (Val(Answer(j)))
       ansArr(j, k - 1) += 1
    Next
Next
For Each a_ansArr As Integer In ansArr
    MessageBox.Show(a_ansArr.ToString) 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Look good to me. I will test and let you know how it goes

Comment: Perfect! I checked it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I did this in a console instead of a WinForms, but the principle is the same. Instead of using a stock 2-d array, I would switch to a `SortedList(Of Integer, Integer)`. Since you're maintaining a sum for each individual question and your questions are "keyed" by number, then you should end up with a list of 17 entries each keyed by question number. The value you store in the list is the current "running" sum, and then ultimately it is accessed by key (question number):

```
    Dim answerSums As New SortedList(Of Integer, Integer)

    ' I have substituted a simple string array in place
    ' Of your data source. 
    Dim rows As String() = {
        "1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2;2;1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2",
        "1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2;2;1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2",
        "1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2;2;1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2",
        "1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2;2;1;2;3;1;2;3;2;2"
    }

    ' Cycle through your data rows
    For I As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1

        ' Get your split questions values
        Dim Answer() As String = rows(I).Split(";")

        ' Cycle through each answer value
        For J As Integer = 1 To Answer.Length

            ' Convert it to a calculable number
            Dim newSum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Answer(J - 1))

            ' If it already exists in your SortedList, add it to the previous value
            If (answerSums.ContainsKey(J)) Then
                newSum += answerSums(J)
            End If

            ' Set the SortedList value to the new summation
            answerSums(J) = newSum
        Next
    Next

    For Each key As Integer In answerSums.Keys
        Console.WriteLine("Answer {0} sum: {1}{2}", key.ToString(), answerSums(key).ToString(), Environment.NewLine)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel, even the 2-D array code are the one I am working on, I will check and learn yours as well. Thanks again